# In Android Studio Hedgehog on Ubuntu Linux, the F8 and F9 keys don't work during debug

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

I recently updated Android Studio Giraffe to Hedgehog on my Linux Ubuntu laptop (Dell XPS 13) and now, when I'm debugging, the F8 and F9 keys don't behave as expected. F8 is a no-op, F9 displays all open windows and the Stop button is a no-op. I can run my projects without any problem, it's just a problem in Debug mode. Anyone know what's going on? It's as if Studio is passing function key events directly to Ubuntu or else Ubuntu is intercepting the events.
UPDATE: I found that I now need to press the Fn key when selecting F8 or F9. Never had to do that before. Is this an Ubuntu gotcha or a Hedgehog gotcha?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect my last update of Ubuntu removed a setting that kept the Fn key locked, so pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> locked key (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) at the same time does what I want.